# Code runs in Spyder but errors out in Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, sybase, pyodbc

I've written a script in Python to execute an external .sql file and export the results to Excel.  I've written the script in Spyder(Python 3.6).  When I run the complete file in Spyder, it runs and exports the data to Excel with no errors.  I've tried to run the script in Anaconda Prompt, but I get an error relating to the Sybase ODBC Driver.

I've investigated this error, however I don't understand why it's not appearing when the code is run within Spyder, only when run in the Anaconda prompt.  Is there a way to check if these environments are different?

I've investigated this error by searching the internet, however I don't understand why it's not appearing when the code is run within Spyder, only when run in the Anaconda prompt.  Is there a way to check if these environments are different?  Ideally, I'd be able to run my script on the command line, not only through an IDE.

The error that I get from the Anaconda Prompt is the following: 
"pyodbc.Error: ('ZZZZZ', "[ZZZZZ] [Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]The 'CREATE TABLE' command is not allowed within a multi-statement transaction in the 'tempdb' database.\n (2762) (SQLExecDirectW)")
"

I expect that running the script in Anaconda Prompt should give the exact same results (no error, successful export to Excel file) as when doing so in Spyder.

Comment: "The 'CREATE TABLE' command is not allowed within a multi-statement transaction" - Try opening your connection with autocommit enabled, e.g., `pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=True)`

Comment: Gord's solution solved my problem.